# Javascript Module pattern with DOM ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a JS Module pattern to test out code and help me understand the pattern, using a JS Fiddle. What I can't figure out is why my "private methods" on line 25 and 26, when referenced via DOM ready, have a value of *undefined*.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dego89/z4Pb8/3/)

Code Sample:

```
var obj = {
    key: "value"
};

var Module = (function () {

  var innerVar = "5";

  console.log("obj var in Module:");
  console.log(obj);

function privateFunction() {
    console.log("privateFunction() called.");
    innerFunction();

    function innerFunction() {
        console.log("inner function of (private function) called.");
    }
}

function _numTwo() {
    console.log("_numTwo() function called.");
}
return {
    test: privateFunction,
    numTwo: _numTwo

}


}(obj));


$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("$ Dom Ready");
    console.log("Module in Dom Ready: ");
    console.log(Module.test());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're outputting the return result of calling privateFunction to the console, which in this case there is none.

```
...
function privateFunction() {
    console.log("privateFunction() called.");
    innerFunction();

    function innerFunction() {
        console.log("inner function of (private function) called.");
    }
    return 'not undefined :)';
}
...
```

Console outputs:

```
obj var in Module: (index):30
Object {key: "value"} (index):31
$ Dom Ready (index):57
Module in Dom Ready:  (index):58
privateFunction() called. (index):34
inner function of (private function) called. (index):38
not undefined :)
```

[See the updated jsFiddle for details](http://jsfiddle.net/z4Pb8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

On the object return:

```
return {
    test: privateFunction(),
    numTwo: _numTwo()

}
```

You are calling the function, you are not passing its reference :).

Remove the brackets, and it should work.

```
return {
    test: privateFunction,
    numTwo: _numTwo

}
```

another way of going things would be:

```
return {
    test: function() { return privateFunction(); },
    numTwo: function() { return _numTwo(); }
}
```

This would return the function to another variable, or just call the function inside the method.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be invoking the 2 functions in your `return` instead of assigning them to the test/numTwo properties.

Maybe you can try this:

```
return {
    test: privateFunction,
    numTwo: _numTwo
}
```

Comment: When I run your [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dego89/z4Pb8/3/) in Chrome, I see that `privateFunction` is invoked when you call `Module.test()`.

Here is what I see in the [Chrome console](http://screencast.com/t/QocfA2dNXdrh).